# vector compiler error for different variable type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

The goal of this assignment for my class is to ask the user for how many students are in the class.
Using the Vector library create a vector of Strings to hold the students names.
Create a vector of type double to hold a students grade average.

I have a couple two compiler errors that are preventing my code from running. Line 73 & 83. The following errors I am given:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void add_student()’: main.cpp:73:11: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘grade’, which is of non-class type ‘double’
73 |     grade.push_back(grade);
   |           ^~~~~~~~~

main.cpp: In function ‘void remove_student()’: main.cpp:83:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
83 |     for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
   |                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Below is my entire code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
vector<string> students;
vector<double> grade;
void add_student();
void remove_student();
void menu();
void print_summary();

int main()
{
    int numStudent;
    char menuSelection; 

    cout << "Welcome to the Student roaster!" << endl;
    cout << "How many students are in your class?:" << endl;
    cin >> numStudent;
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudent; i++)
    {
        add_student();
    }
    cout << "Thank you for entering class information!" << endl;
    

    //calls menu for the user
    menu();


    while (1)
    {
        cout << "selection:" << endl;
        cin >> menuSelection;
        if (menuSelection == 'a')
        {
            add_student();
        }
        else if (menuSelection == 'r')
        {
            remove_student();
        }
        else if (menuSelection == 'p')
        {
            print_summary();
        }
        else if (menuSelection == 'm')
        {
            menu();
        }
        else if (menuSelection == 'q')
            break;
        else
            cout << "Not a valid selection" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
void add_student()
{
    string firstName, lastName;
    double grade;

    //ask for student info
    cout << "Please enter student (Fisrt Last Grade) info: " << endl;
    cin >> firstName >> lastName >> grade;

    firstName += " ";
    firstName += lastName;

    //inserts new student
    students.push_back(firstName); 
    grade.push_back(grade);
}
void remove_student()
{
    string first, last;
    cout << "Enter the student (First Last) to remove :\n";
    cin >> first >> last;
    first += " ";
    first += last;
    int loc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
    {
        if (students[i] == first)
        { // finding the location to erase
            loc = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    students.erase(students.begin() + loc); //removing using erase function
    grade.erase(grade.begin() + loc);
}
void menu()
{
    cout << "Please choose one of the following options:\n";
    cout << "a: add a student\n";
    cout << "r: remove a student\n";
    cout << "p: print the class summary\n";
    cout << "m: print menu\n";
    cout << "q: quit program\n";
}
void print_summary()
{
    cout << "class summary" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Name" << setw(20) << "Grade" << endl;
    cout << "-------" << setw(20) << "--------" << endl;
    int n = students.size();
    double total = 0;

    //cycles through each student
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int temp = students[i].size();
        int loc = 20 - temp;
        cout << students[i] << setw(loc) << grade[i] << endl;
        total += grade[i];
    }
    cout << "Number of students: " << endl;
    cout << "------------------" <<endl;
    cout << n << " " << endl;
    total = (total) / n;
    cout << "Average Grade: " << endl;
    cout << "--------------" << endl;

    //limits the deciaml places to 2
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << total << " " << endl;
}
```

Comment: You have used a same name for vector and the "double grade" variable. in this case compiler double grade since it is define in the scope of add student function. rename "double grade"  to something else and update it wherever it has been used like in "cin" and also input parameter of "grade.push_back()"

Comment: Maybe you should change the name of your `vector<double> grade;` to `vector<double> grades;`

Comment: `grade.push_back(grade)` should make you pause.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the local variable was the same as the name of the global variable.
So you should rename local variable.

```
62)  double grade_;
66)  cin >> firstName >> lastName >> grade_;
73)  grade.push_back(grade_);
```